# transparent border in menu with css

Tags: css, menu, border, transparent

I use a menu like below. How do I change the bottom-border from white to transparent so that the border appears as a transparent border. Now, when I set the border transparent, the entire menu is orange (background color of the menu):

```css
ul#nav,
ul#nav ul {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    list-style: none;
}
ul#nav li {
    position: relative;
    float: left;
    width: 118px;
}
#nav li ul {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: auto;
    margin-left: -999em;
    border-top: 11px transparent;
}
#nav li  li {
    width: 135px;
    z-index: 1;
}
#nav li ul ul {
    position: absolute;
    left: 100%;
    top: -.1em;
    margin-left: -999em;
}
ul#nav li a {
    display: block;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-align: left;
    background: white;
    border: none;
}
* html ul#nav li a { height: 1% }
#nav li:hover a,
#nav li.over a,
#nav li:hover li:hover a,
#nav li.over li.over a,
#nav li:hover li:hover li:hover a,
#nav li.over li.over li.over a,
#nav li:hover li a:hover,
#nav li.over li a:hover,
#nav li:hover li:hover li:hover a:hover,
#nav li.over li li a:hover,
#nav li:hover li:hover li:hover li:hover a:hover,
#nav li.over li.over li.over li.over a:hover {
    color: #ff7f00;
    background-color: white;
}
#nav li:hover li a,
#nav li.over li a,
#nav li:hover li:hover li a,
#nav li.over li.over li a,
#nav li:hover li:hover li:hover li a,
#nav li.over li.over li.over li a {
    color: white;
    background: #ff7f00;
    margin-left: -10px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #FFFFFF;
    filter: alpha(opacity=95);
    -moz-opacity: 0.95;
    opacity: 0.95;
}
#nav li ul li a { padding: 25px 7px 7px 7px }
ul#nav li:hover ul ul,
ul#nav li:hover ul ul ul,
ul#nav li.over ul ul,
ul#nav li.over ul ul ul { margin-left: -999em }
ul#nav li:hover ul,
ul#nav li li:hover ul,
ul#nav li li li:hover ul,
u#navl li li li li:hover ul,
ul#nav li.over ul,
ul#nav li li.over ul,
ul#nav li li li.over ul { margin-left: 0 }
```

Comment: Please make a jsfiddle so its easier for others to understand and answer your question. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

```
border-bottom:2px solid rgba(0,0,0,.5);
```

Answer (score 0):

this code is very difficult to read as it is presented. I presume you have tried
 `border-bottom: 1px transparent; ?`

Comment: Yes, I tried that, but then the border takes the background color of the menu. The entire CSS can be seen at http://www.catchsolar.no/CSS/pages.css

Comment: Can you not just set the border to be the background color of the menu then? Or is it a gradient?

Comment: line 68 of pages.css is where you control the border color. I think i see what you are after now. Setting the border to 'transparent' will not show the page behind it, it will simply tighten up the div's removing any border. To achieve the effect your after you need to put a gap between the list items. You can achieve this via : #nav li li {
    margin-bottom: 1px; }

Comment: I tried that also, but then the menu collapsed since the background gets focus when the mouse is moved between the menu-items.

Comment: set a margin on focus/acitve also

Comment: try #nav li:hover, #nav li:active, #nav li:focus { margin-bottom: 1px; }

Comment: I don't know why, but it will not work. Either the entire page below moves or the menu collapse when the margin gets focus.

Answer (score 0):

Simply use

```
border-bottom: none;
```

[Demo](http://jsbin.com/ezoqet)

Answer (score 0):

Either use

```
border-bottom: none;
```

Or, if you still want to maintain a gap, simply set the colour to `transparent`:

```
border-bottom-color: transparent;
```