# How to draw real transparent border with CSS?

Tags: css, border

Note: There seems to be a [same problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11395663/transparent-border-in-menu-with-css) before but I hope to ask it in better way, get an answer to mark as solved.

In short, transparent element borders are not really transparent because they take the color of the element background instead of being invisible eventhough it is drawn as an "outside border". How can I draw real transparent border with CSS?

**Why do I want this?**

Because I have a [CSS menu with drop down on hover](http://jsfiddle.net/gkbcj9sr/4/). Between the main menu and the sub menu, there is a requirement for a gap in between. The gap causes the hover to lose focus, thereby closing the menu. There may be other ways to do it, but transparent border, if possible, will be as neat.

**HTML**

```
<ul id="root">
    <li>Item 1
        <ul><li>Subitem 1</li></ul>
    </li>
    <li>Item 2
        <ul><li>Subitem 2</li></ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

**CSS**

```
ul, li {
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0; padding: 0;
    color: #fff;
}
ul ul { background-color: red; }
ul#root > li {
    background-color: blue;
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative
}
ul#root > li > ul {
    position: absolute;
    display: none;
    /* margin-top: 10px; want to have gap but the hover will lose focus*/
    border-top: 10px solid green; /* if only this is transparent */
}
ul#root > li:hover > ul {
    position: absolute;
    display: block;
}
```

Comment: Have you tried `border-top: 10px solid transparent` ? Isn't that what you're looking for? Why do you say transparent borders aren't transparent? What exactly do you want? Look this, it's transparent isn't it? http://jsfiddle.net/gkbcj9sr/3/

Comment: @Cyberdelphos This is embarrassing. The fiddle is incorrect. I have edited the code now.

Answer (score 1):

Use background color for li  instead of ul & use padding top

```
ul#root > li > ul { padding-top:10px; background: transparent; }
ul#root > li > ul > li { background: #f00; }
```

or Use

```
ul#root > li > ul { border-top :10px solid rgba(0,0,0,0); }
```

or

```
ul#root > li > ul { border-top :10px solid transparent; }
```

Comment: this is exactly why it [worked initially](http://jsfiddle.net/gkbcj9sr/1/), causing the confusion. The question though, is how to draw real transparent borders. In my case, ul ul li have to be styled differently, and the background-color must be on ul ul

Answer (score 1):

`enter code here`http://jsfiddle.net/gkbcj9sr/2/

use rgba colour, but check if all browsers support them or not.

Answer (score 0):

Check this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/gkbcj9sr/6/

I changed a little your css in order to keep your html intact:

Changed the `ul ul` rule, to `ul ul li` in order to add the background to li and not to the entire ul which was causing you troubles.

Added `border-top: transparent` to your `ul#root > li > ul` rule, to have your transparent gap.

Here's the new css:

```
ul, li {
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0; padding: 0;
    color: #fff;
}
#root { border: 1px solid green; }
ul ul li { background-color: red; } /* Background only in your li elemnts
ul#root > li {
    background-color: blue;
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative
}
ul#root > li > ul {
    position: absolute;
    display: none;
    /* margin-top: 10px; want to have gap but the hover will trigger */
    border-top: 10px solid transparent; /* transparent border top */
}
ul#root > li:hover > ul {
    position: absolute;
    display: block;
}
```

Hope this was you were looking for.

Comment: this is exactly why it [worked initially](http://jsfiddle.net/gkbcj9sr/1/), causing the confusion. The question though, is how to draw real transparent borders. In my case, `ul ul li` have to be styled differently, and the `background-color` must be on `ul ul`.